# MySQL InnoDB foreign key between different databases

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, innodb

I would like to know if it's possible in InnoDB in `MySQL` to have a `table` with **foreign key** that references another table in a different `database` ?

And if so, how this can be done ?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I do not see any limitation on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html.

So just use **otherdb.othertable** and you will be good.

Comment: @Code4R7 Make sure the tables use the same engine, as by the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/foreign-keys/): "_The parent and the child table must use the same storage engine[...]"_

To change table's engine,
`ALTER TABLE my_table ENGINE = InnoDB;`

Worked for MariaDB 10.1.16.

Answer (score 32):

It's possible :  [Link to do it](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,150829,200251#msg-200251)

Example (Table1 is in database1 and HelloTable is in database2) :

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 
ADD foreign key FK_table1(ColumnNameFromTable1)
REFERENCES db2.HelloTable(ColumnNameFromHelloTable)
```

Comment: +1 Must add that if in addition to the link, had you summarized the contents of the link in the answer here, would be a bit more helpful!

Comment: -1 A link is not enough, answer should contain more information (explanation or example).

Answer (score 7):

Below is how to add a foreign key on table t2, reference from table db1.historial(codh):

```
alter table t2
add foreign key FK_t2(micod2)
    references db1.historial(codh)
    on delete cascade
    on update cascade;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename1`
ADD CONSTRAINT `tablename1_student_id_foreign` 
FOREIGN KEY (`tablename1`.`id`) 
REFERENCES `db2`.`tablename2`(`id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

if we have table calling answers in db1 and student in db2 calling ramiyusu_offline

we must type as below

```
ALTER TABLE `answers`
ADD CONSTRAINT `answers_student_id_foreign` 
FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
REFERENCES `ramiyusu_offline`.`student`(`id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```