# Users and companies - database scheme

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a project management app, where every company (which uses our app) will have a personal subdomain: company.domain.com. For many reasons I decided to use a separate database for each company.

Companies can invite people (by email) to work together on projects. A user can belong to multiple companies (so should appear in multiple databases). However, user data, and login information are stored in a seperate db because users use the same username, password for each company, and their first name, and last name is the same for each company.

What I do now, is the following:

- there exists a separate database with: users, identities (user_id, username, password).
- there also exists a *users* table in every database of each company, containing the same data about the user (actually only 3 fields: first name, last name, time zone).

Is there a better solution for this?
If you have questions about the question :) please ask.

I'm using php + mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think having the user data amongst more data tables is correct - think about redundancy...

If You have a database containing user data, why not having company databases linked to this database for user data?

A simple image:
[image: Example on how to divide users tables]

Within Your companies databases You then can have additional company based user data within users table but the common data should remain only once per storage...

EDIT: ORA storage is just for example, You can use a MySQL database as well...

Comment: Exactly! The redundancy is the problem here. I don't want to store the same data twice. Thank you for your answer, and +1 for the schema.

I'll make some benchmark test for multiple db selects, and cross db foreign keys.

Comment: To be honest I have never used `multidatabase` foreign keys (yet never had to) and If I would have to do this I would consider using MS SQL or better ORACLE for this, but it should be also wroking within MySQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905013/mysql-innodb-foreign-key-between-different-databases